# Failed to create symbolic link: File exist

Tags: server, 18.04, nginx, symbolic-link

This is sort of recurring question in here, but I read all the answers I could found and it did not made it clearer to me what should I do, please help me since I am completely new to Ubuntu and VPS altogether. I am trying to deploy simple website I developed through django.

While following [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn) (and some other various material), I stumbled to the point where according to the guides I have to (quoting guide):

1. > Now we need to set up a symbolic link in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory that points to this configuration file. Change directories to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`.

   I have done that with:

   ```
   cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
   ```
2. > Once there, run this command:
   >
   > ```
   > sudo ln -s ../sites-available/myproject
   > ```

   Since from the beginning of the guide I used `skaiciuokle_web` project name instead of `myproject`, that is the only place where I deviate from guide and use the command:

   ```
   sudo ln -s ../sites-available/skaiciuokle_web
   ```

After running the `sudo ln -s` command I get this error:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/skaiciuokle_web': File exists`
```

Despite probably reading all the previous questions, I still cannot understand why I am getting this error, because I (almost) followed the guides to the letter.

Could somebody point me to the right direction?

Comment: Probably, your system is right: the file already exists and you try to create it again.  Could you post the output of `ls -l skaiciuokle_web'?

Comment: Yes, this is the what command line shows after I put `ls -l skaiciuokle-web` : `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 34 sep 27 08:36 skaiciuokle_web -> ../sites-available/skaiciuokle_web` . I have no idea what that means... it means that it exist?

Comment: It means that the first time your ran the command...it worked. Success means NO output. You perhaps didn't realize that and mistakenly thought the lack of output meant failure or a mistake. Common new-user mistake. Everybody does it once.

Comment: Thank you! I have much to learn in understanding how servers and even command line works. I would upvote both of you, but do not have that right in here yet.

Comment: FYI, when answering questions that ask you "what happens when...", don't post the answer as a comment (which doesn't have good formatting) but instead post it by editing your question. I did this for you.

Answer (score 4):

You can overwrite the existing file *../sites-enabled/myproject* by forcing `ln` like this

`sudo ln -sf ../sites-available/myproject ../sites-enabled/`

then

`sudo service nginx restart`